# Search array and sub array on String property?

Tags: swift

I have the following code in a playground:

```
struct Car: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
}
struct Dealer: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var cars:[Car]
}
struct Response: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    let id:UUID
    var dealers:[Dealer]
}

var result = Response(id:UUID(), dealers: [])

func setup() {
    
    
    // MOCK FOR NOW
    var dealers = [Dealer]()
    for n in 0..<15 {
        var cars = [Car]()
        for c in 0..<100 {
            cars.append(Car(id: c+n, name: "Car \(c)_\(n)"))
        }
        dealers.append(Dealer(id: n, name: "Dealer \(n)", cars: cars))
    }
    
    result = Response(id:UUID(), dealers: dealers)
}

setup()

//print("result: \(result)")

let searchResult = result.dealers.filter { dealer in
    dealer.name.contains("Dealer 0")
}
```

So it's an array of dealers and each has an array of cars.

Both a Dealer and a Car have a name:String property. Given a search string, "Car 23_0" for example, I would like to filter out the `result` so that the Dealer containing that car is kept as a section header (I'm using this to drive a sectioned table) and also show the car row... So want to search for cars by name out of the `result` that gets constructed in this code. If I want to search Dealers I can easily do this:

```
let searchResult = result.dealers.filter { dealer in
    dealer.name.contains("Dealer 0")
}
```

I am not sure how to search by car.name on `result`.

How can I filter out any car in `result` that does not satisfy the `.contains("Cat 23_0")`?

Comment: So you want the result to be an array of `Dealer`.  Do you want the `cars` array in each `Dealer` to only contain the cars that matched or do you want the full inventory of the `Dealer` that has the matched car?

Comment: Former. I want to keep only the dealers that have cars that match the contains condition on the car name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to find dealers of cars with an specific name in the response:

```
extension Response {
    func dealersForCar(name: String) -> [Dealer] {
        dealers.filter { $0.cars.contains { $0.name == name } }
    }
}
```

and to get the cards with an specific name from a dealer

```
extension Dealer {
    func cars(name: String) -> [Car] {
        cars.filter { $0.name == name }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
// to find dealers in the response
let searchedDealers = result.dealersForCar(name: "Car 67_12")

// to find cars in the dealer
searchedDealers.first?.car(name: "Car 67_12")
```